# Grouping excel output in Pentaho Kettle Spoon

Tags: kettle

How to group the Excel output by the column value in Pentaho Kettle Spoon?
The idea is:

If I have a table

```
client cost
------------
a      10
a      20
b      15
b      5
a      30
```

to receive Excel output like (to group by client)

```
client cost
------------
a      10
a      20
a      30

client cost
------------
b      15
b      5
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to repeat the headings? sounds to me more like you're creating a report not an ETL.

If you just want to group  and sort then use the group by step with a sort on client beforehand.  And add an aggregate of sum or whatever you need for cost.

if you really want to control the format and have duplicated headings, then i would look at sending the data to the pentaho reporting step, and create a report for the output. you would still need the data sorted by the group which is "client" but then you can do all your headings in the pentaho report itself, and you then have full control over the final output format.